# On delete cascade alternate

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a database for child and parent. Tables looks like.

> **ChildTable**  :  *child-id*(pk) | *parent-id*(fk) | *name*
>
> **ParentTable** : *parent-id*(pk) | *name*
>
> ***FOREIGN KEY ParentTable(parent-id) REFERENCES  ChildTable(parent-id) ON DELETE CASCADE***

**Problem:**  a parent can have more than one children and parent table is dependent on child table. If a parent is having two children and we delete one children record from ***ChildTable*** it would delete the parent as well while parent record must exist for another child whose record is still in database.

Is there any other MySQL method/constraint that can fulfill the above requirement.

Thanks in advance.

> **Update:** I would like to explain my problem in detail.

I want to apply following rules to the database:

- A record in parent table must be always dependent of any one or two records in child table. (FK was added for the same.)
- There is possibility that 2 children can point to same parentID
- if we delete one child having parentID (say 'abc') then parent id must not be deleted if there exists another child having same parentID.
- on deleting the second child with same parentID('abc') now it must be deleted as there is no child with parentID('abc').

Answer (score 3):

Your foreign key should be reversed:

```
FOREIGN KEY parent-id REFERENCES ParentTable(parent-id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

You want the child table to reference a primary key in the parent table. Be careful though with the cascading delete: when you delete a parent row, you automatically delete all its child rows.

When you delete one child row, nothing happens to the parent row.

**UPDATE**: What you want can only be accomplished using a trigger. You need to create an `AFTER DELETE` trigger on `ChildTable` that checks whether a row from `ParentTable` can be removed.

Comment: I tried your solution but phpMyAdmin gave error.. also I want parent table to be dependable on Child Table if we reverse the foreign key it would change the dependency while i want to delete the parent record only when there is no child left.

Comment: i have updated my question with few more details. hope that would explain you my problem. I also searched MYSQL manual but didn't found anything similar.